# http://localhost:8080/ works, http://127.0.0.1:8080/ doesn't works why?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

What gives? When I view the page as `"http://localhost:8080/"` from the local machine, I can create the first (administrator) account and login without any problem. However, when I view the page from any other machine via it's public and/or private IPs, or even `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` LOCALLY, I experience the "can't login or create the first (administrator) account" problem. What is going on?

Comment: Generate static ip in your system & then that id will work for you as " http://YOUR_IP:8080/ "
refer this :-http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/static-ip-address-advantages-disadvantages/

Answer (score 1):

First localhost exist only on your own machine. All other machines will try to look at themselves. Second, the reason for not being able to accessing your computer from another is dependent on your apache configuration. From what you say you probably have a WAMP configuration, these are usually only for development use as they are not secure enough. So, if you want you can of course change the apache parameters, which I don't think is a good thing. Or migrate the wp installation to a public server. If the problem persists on your localhost that is because of your settings in wordpress. Check reading settings in wp-admin or if you cannot connect you can also alter the settings by phpmyadmin. Hope this makes sense.